# NextJs dynamic rendering (blinking)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have some issues with dynamic import of the component in my NextJs app. I'm trying to import Froala text editor and it's supported for React. But, when I try to import it, I have errors that window is not defined, so I'm importing it with next/dynamic.

So the problem is, this editor should not reload on every change on page. Whatever I do, ex. change state, it will rerender the component. It's only blinking, but still cannot show like so to the client. Is there any other way I could use component and not "blink"?

Here is my component:

```
import FroalaEditor from 'react-froala-wysiwyg';

const Froala = (props: {model: any, onChanged: any}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <FroalaEditor model={props.model} onModelChange={props.onChanged} config={{
                toolbarButtons: ['fullscreen', 'bold', 'italic', 'textColor', 'backgroundColor', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'color', 'inlineClass', 'inlineStyle', 'paragraphStyle', 'paragraphFormat', 'align', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'outdent', 'indent', 'quote', 'insertLink', 'insertImage', 'insertVideo', 'embedly', 'insertFile', 'insertTable', 'emoticons', 'fontAwesome', 'specialCharacters', 'insertHR', 'selectAll', 'clearFormatting', 'print', 'getPDF', 'spellChecker', 'help', 'html', 'undo', 'redo'],
                toolbarButtonsXS: ['bold', 'italic', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'undo', 'redo'],
                placeholderText: 'Edit Your Content Here!',
                charCounterCount: false,
                theme: 'dark',
                imageUploadParam: 'image_param',
                fileUploadMethod: 'POST',
                fileUploadURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload_file',
                // Set the image upload URL.
                imageUploadMethod: 'POST',
                imageUploadURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload/image',
                // Set request type.

                // Set max image size to 5MB.
                imageMaxSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024,

                // Allow to upload PNG and JPG.
                imageAllowedTypes: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'],
            }}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Froala
```

And importing to other components would be:

```
 const FroalaEditor = dynamic(() => import('../Froala'), {
        ssr: false
    });
```

It's not important what I change on the page... dispatch, state, or whatever that can cause rerendering, it will blink. How can I prevent this?

Btw, if component is directly imported, it's giving an error of undefined window!

Answer (score 0):

This answer covers only "blink" issue, but not the Next/import related part.

I had exactly the same blinking problem with `FroalaEditor` imported from `'react-froala-wysiwyg'`.

Solved the issue by importing the package at `index.html` from the internet or locally from `node_modules` as described [here](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/overview/).

```
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor@latest/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor@latest/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js'></script>
```

Later in react you need to instantiate the Froala only once on componet's initial load inside `useEffect` with empty dependency array.

In case you need to access froala methods later in the code you may store the froala object in some external variable or inside `useRef`.

```
    import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"

    export default function App() {
      const froalaElementRef = useRef()
      const froalaInstanceRef = useRef()
      const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1)

      useEffect(() => {
        froalaInctanceRef.current = new FroalaEditor(
          froalaElementRef.current,
          {
            theme: "dark"
            // other froala options
          },
          function () {
            this.html.set("initial text")
          }
        )
      }, [])

      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h3>Froala which does not blink on re-renders</h3>
          <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>Update counter to re-render the component with Froala</button>
          <h2>{counter}</h2>
          <button onClick={() => alert(froalaInstanceRef.current.html.get())}>Get froala content</button>
          <div ref={froalaElementRef} style={{ margin: 20 }} />
        </div>
      )
    }
```

You can play with froala in sandbox and force the page to re-render by changing the counter.

https://codesandbox.io/s/froala-which-does-not-blink-i9lwrp

Froala is not re-instantiated on every render and text does not blink.